# to retrieve stringlist items in memo from table POS_CatBreakDownValue into tchecklistbox

Tags: delphi

i have a problem on how to retrieve the items in memo from table into tchecklistbox...before this i do the procedure to insert the items that have been checked into memo in tbl POS_CatBreakDownValue..but now i want to know how to retrieve items from table and automatic check in tchecklistbox...thanks..here  my procedure to insert the checklist into memo in table..i hope anyone can help me..thanks

```
procedure TfrmSysConfig.saveCatBreakDownValue;   
var  
 lstCat:TStringList;                                                                       
 i     :integer;  
begin  
  lstcat := TStringList.Create;  
  try   
   for i:=0 to clCat.Items.Count-1 do begin  
     if clCat.Checked[i] then begin  
       lstcat.Add(clcat.Items.Strings[i]);  
     end;  
   end;  
   tblMainPOS_CatBreakDownValue.Value := lstCat.Text;  
  finally  
  lstcat.Free;  
  end;  
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TfrmSysConfig.saveCatBreakDownValue;
var 
    lstCat: TStringList;
    i:integer;
begin
    lstcat := TStringList.Create;
    try
        for i:=0 to clCat.Items.Count-1 do begin
            if clCat.Checked[i] then begin
                lstcat.Add(clcat.Items.Strings[i]);
            end;
        end;
        tblMainPOS_CatBreakDownValue.Value := lstCat.Text;
    finally
        lstcat.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Reading your code I'm guessing you've got a MemoField in a database that you are reading and writing the checked values from/to.  You also have a predefined list of checkable items.

So you'll need to create a new string list and read the field back into it (Revesing the writing code). for each item in the list get the Index and check it.

Something like..

```
procedure TfrmSysConfig.saveCatBreakDownValue;
var 
    lstCat: TStringList;
    i, Index:integer;
begin
    lstcat := TStringList.Create;
    try
        lstcat.Text = tblMainPOS_CatBreakDownValue.Value;
        for i:=0 to lstcat.Count-1 do 
        begin
            Index := clCat.Items.IndexOf(lstcat.Items[i]) 
            if Index > -1 then 
            begin
                clCat.Checked[Index] := True;
            end;
        end;
    finally
        lstcat.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question 100%

TCheckListBox can check or uncheck items using the `Checked` Property.

```
  CheckListBox.Checked[Index] := True/False;
```

Since you sound like your comparing strings you may need to determine the index in the TCheckListBox based on the string this can be done like this:

```
  CheckListBox1.Items.IndexOf('StringToFind')
```

If the string is not found then the result is -1;

If you want to check lines in a TMemo Control and see if they exists as rows in a table you can do the following.

```
While not Table.EOF do
begin
  if Memo1.lines.IndexOf(Table.FieldByName('MyField').AsString) = -1 then
  begin
   // What you want to do if not found
  end
  else
  begin
   // what you want to do if it is found.
  end;
  Table.Next;
end;
```